# Unable to instantiate application error: Android studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 RC 1 with version catalog

Tags: android, kotlin, runtime

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.nativethings.noteapp.NotesApp package  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find application class on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~8jI8LDfrOLtsT4_mpKVSog==/com.nativethings.noteapp-L7dUjYUUiOBjUhLF7V-7oA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~8jI8LDfrOLtsT4_mpKVSog==/com.nativethings.noteapp-L7dUjYUUiOBjUhLF7V-7oA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]

I created a simple room data layer, with hilt injection

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.room.Room
import com.nativethings.noteapp.data.local.NoteDatabase
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideNoteDatabase(
        context: Application
    ): NoteDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context = context,
            NoteDatabase::class.java,
            name = NoteDatabase.NOTE_DB
        ).build()
    }
    
}
```

```
import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class NotesApp : Application() {
}
```

Comment: You have tagged your question with `Java` but the code you have posted seems to be Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have added `Application` reference in `AndroidManifes.xml` file.

pass Application class path to `name` attitbute.

```
<application
        android:name="YOUR_APP_CLASS"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ComposeTutorials">
        ...
    </application>
```

Comment: I've already mentioned the application class in manifest , like android:name = ".NotesApp"